# How can I denote a field that can be either Rc<T> or Weak<T>

Tags: rust

I'd like to have a field in struct like this:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: Smart<T>
}
```

where bar could be either `Rc<T` or `Weak<T>`, depending on the "ownership relationships" between different instances of Foo. Is there any idiomatic way in Rust how to do this, other than to create a custom enum?

Comment: I don't think that such a type exist, but I'm not sure that it is a good idea: weak vs rc allows to model an ownership relation. For example, a parent owns a child (`Rc<Child>`) while the child points to its owner: `Weak<Parent>`. Being unable to distinguish this fundamental difference can be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any idiomatic way in Rust how to do this, other than to create a custom enum?

Just like most other "either this or that" choices in Rust, an `enum` ***is*** the idiomatic way.

Comment: The OP's question (IIUC) is: is there such an abstraction in the std. Writing such an enum by hand can require a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios std doesn't provide anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

An Peter's answer suggested, there is is no such abstraction in the stdlib. You can define a small enum to handle both cases:

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

enum MaybeStrong<T> {
    Strong(Rc<T>),
    Weak(Weak<T>),
}

impl<T> MaybeStrong<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<Rc<T>> {
        match self {
            MaybeStrong::Strong(t) => Some(Rc::clone(t)),
            MaybeStrong::Weak(w) => w.upgrade(),
        }
    }
}

struct Foo<T> {
    bar: MaybeStrong<T>
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn from_weak(inner: Weak<T>) -> Self {
        Self { bar: MaybeStrong::Weak(inner) }
    }

    fn from_strong(inner: Rc<T>) -> Self {
        Self { bar: MaybeStrong::Strong(inner) }
    }

    fn say(&self) where T: std::fmt::Debug {
        println!("{:?}", self.bar.get())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let inner = Rc::new("foo!");
    Foo::from_weak(Rc::downgrade(&inner)).say();
    Foo::from_strong(inner).say();
}
```

`self.bar()` will always return a `Some` if it was created from a strong pointer and return `None` in case it's a `Weak` and it's dangling. Notice that due to the fact that `get()` needs to create an owned `Rc` first, the method can't return a `&T` (including `Option<&T>`) because that `&T` could be dangling. This also means that all users of `bar()` will own one strong count on the inner value while processing, making it safe to use in any case.

Comment: Since `get()` will always imply memory writes (increment/decrement the counter), it could be valuable to provide an in-place `apply(f: FnOnce(Option<&T>) -> R) -> R` method which would not need to perform those writes in the `Strong` case. The trait bound will require `for<'a>`.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of construct is often called "Either" and there's a crate that looks like it can address some of the usual use-cases: https://docs.rs/either/1.5.3/either/

Then you could write

```
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: Either<Weak<T>, Rc<T>>
}
```

Then an example function to get an `Option<Rc<T>>` might be:

```
impl <T> Foo<T> {
  fn get_rc(self) -> Option<Rc<T>> {
     self.bar
       .map_left( |weak| weak.upgrade() )
       .map_right( |v| Some(v) )
       .into_inner()
  }
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Rc::new(1);
    let f_direct = Foo{ bar:Either::Right(x.clone()) };
    println!("f_direct.get_rc() = {:?}", f_direct.get_rc());
    let f_weak = Foo{ bar:Either::Left(Rc::downgrade(&x)) };
    println!("f_weak.get_rc() = {:?}", f_weak.get_rc());
}
```

Link to complete example in the playground:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c20faaa46277550e16a3d3b24f3d1750

Comment: @MatthieuM. I didn't think either would be in the playgrounds list of crates - but it turns out it is. So I've fixed up the code (was one minor bug) and linked to a complete exampled. Thanks.